# Can one fake a paypal payment?

Tags: paypal

I am updating my Paypal Integration from good old NVP to the new Script.

With the old ExpressCheckout, returnURL's where handed over from my backend server through paypal for success or failure. These URL's could carry a random parameter and thus protect against someone faking the paypal responses (as I could verify that these responses carry the same parameter as given to paypal at order creation time from my server).

The current Javascript from Paypal just calls a onApprove() method and its up to me to tell this approval to my server.

As there are no returnURL's handed over anymore, there is also no way to protect the callback from being faked. Someone inspecting my (clientside javascript) code or observing the traffic from the browser can just handcraft that call and tell my server that paypal successfully authorized.

Is my reasoning wrong?
Is there any other way to prevent this scenario?